# Form onsubmit not triggered by inlined javascript

Tags: javascript, forms, laravel, laravel-blade, dom-events

My issue comes when I click on the button, the form is submitted just fine, but the inlined `onsubmit` event is not called, so the confirmation alert is never printed.

My code:

```
<!-- Delete button -->
<a onclick="document.getElementById('delete-form-`+ data.id +`').submit();" class="icon">
    <i class="mdi mdi-delete"></i>
</a>

<!-- Hidden form -->
<form id="delete-form-`+ data.id +`" action="`+ 'posts/'+ data.id +`"
    style="display: none;" 
    onsubmit="return confirm('Are you sure you want to perform this action?');">
    {{ method_field('DELETE') }}
    {{ csrf_field() }}
</form>
```

I don't know if this is meant to happen, is there any reason? I would like to keep it inlined, do you have any solution?

**EDIT:** You may have noticed by the quotes I'm using but this piece of code is being inserted in the DOM using javascript, I thought it's worth to mention.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Which JS error you getting?

Comment: @AddWebSolutionPvtLtd As I said the form is being submitted fine, so there are no errors, it just ignores the `onsubmit` in the form and gets to the controller with no previous confirmation.

Comment: you could bind form to `onclick` instead of `onsubmit`.

Comment: @0decimal0 But the form is hidden, how am I supposed to click on it?

Comment: Bind it to a button then .

Comment: @0decimal0 That's what I've already done, but on an anchor, do you expect a different outcome?

Comment: When you call onclick on anchor the form is submitted then why do expect another onsubmit function to be called.

Comment: @0decimal0 Onsubmit is called when the form is submitted, then if I submit it using the anchor, it should be triggered, but it's not.

Comment: Let me know if you want to go with other option?

Comment: @AddWebSolutionPvtLtd What do you mean by other option? The solution is pretty straight forward but I would really like to know **why** this is happening and keep it inlined.

Comment: What do you expect this part to do: `'delete-form-\`+ data.id +\`'`?

Comment: @Asur: I'm not sure but may be when you call the form's submit function, the submit event is not fired. May be this is by design, and taken the assumption is that if you're triggering the submission from code means you've already done any necessary validation.

Comment: @BenM This code is a template, part of a loop, it basically creates a unique id so the form can be referenced correctly.

Comment: Okay, so why not just use a traditional `<button type="submit" />` and style it to look like your link?

Comment: @AddWebSolutionPvtLtd Well, that's exactly the problem I have. That's an interesting point of view, but if true, it would be mentioned somewhere, or more people would have had the same problem.

Comment: @BenM Yes, that's the temporary solution I've done, the problem is not lack of possibilities, but now I need to scratch this itch and find out why this is happening.

Comment: @Asur: Got the origin of my word: Check [this](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-control-infrastructure.html#concept-form-submit)

Comment: @Asur: Hope now you clear, correct?

Comment: @AddWebSolutionPvtLtd Not really, I just took a different way, but I still don't know why that isn't working.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure you can use more than one id for the same element and + for separate them

```
<form id="delete-form-`+ data.id +`"
```

Comment: As I mentioned, that code is part of a loop, so the `data.id` is incrementing, so never is the same.